# How do I pipe output from node stdout to open command in Mac terminal?

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I have a node project where I output a filename to `stdout` in the terminal with `process.stdout.write(filename + '\n');`. How can I pipe this output to the `open` command or some other command to open the file (an image in this case) with the default image viewer?

Comment: `node some_node_file.js | open -f` As far as I know `open` waits filename as an argument, so it's just bash issue.

Comment: Piping into `open -f` simply opens the output text (a.k.a. the file name) in the default text editor. It doesn't open the image file with the default image viewer.

Comment: If you want it to open a specific application, you need to pass `-a <appname>`. I guess you need `Preview` for images.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) points out in the comments, you will need to pass `-a <appname>` to open the file with a specific application.
However, you will need to pipe the file to stdout instead of just the filename, fore example like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream("./test.jpg").pipe(process.stdout);
```

and then of yourse `node yourNodeFile.js | open -f -a Preview.app`